# Is there a way to separate all the faces from an object and lay them flat?

Tags: modeling

I’m working on welding a geometric object and I was wondering if there was any way to separate the faces from the object and lay them flat so I can cut them out on my CNC plasma table.

This is the object in question:
[image]

Comment: Try the paper folding export add on. It might be just the thing for this :-)

Comment: Also UV unwrapping the model without deformation should do the trick